# Backbone error: Model is not a constructor

Tags: backbone.js, collections, model, require

Afternoon all, I'm relatively new to backbone and have been stumped for 3 days with this error which I have not seen before.

I have a collection 'TestCollection' which defines it's model as a function. When the collection is loaded I get an error the first time it attempts to make a model with class 'TestModel'.

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: TestModel is not a constructor
at new model (testCollection.js:14)
at child._prepareModel (backbone.js:913)
at child.set (backbone.js:700)
at child.add (backbone.js:632)
at child.reset (backbone.js:764)
at Object.options.success (backbone.js:860)
at fire (jquery.js:3143)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3255)
at done (jquery.js:9309)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:9713)
```

I believe I have given both the collection and the model all of the code they should need to work. It feels like something has gone wrong with the loading, but when I put a console.log at the top of the model file I could see that it is definitely being loaded before the collection attempts to use it.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

TestCollection:

```
define([
  'backbone',
  'models/testModel'
], function(Backbone, TestModel) {

  var TestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: function(attrs) {
      switch (attrs._type) {
        case 'test':
          console.log('making a test model')
          return new TestModel();
      }
    },

    initialize : function(models, options){
      this.url = options.url;
      this._type = options._type;
      this.fetch({reset:true});
    }

  });

  return TestCollection;

});
```

TestModel:

```
require([
  './testParentModel'
], function(TestParentModel) {

  var TestModel = TestParentModel.extend({

    urlRoot: 'root/url',

    initialize: function() {
      console.log('making test model')
    }
  });

  return TestModel;
});
```

File where TestCollection is made:

```
define(function(require) {

  var MyProjectCollection = require('collections/myProjectCollection');
  var TestCollection = require('collections/testCollection');

  Origin.on('router:dashboard', function(location, subLocation, action) {



  Origin.on('dashboard:loaded', function (options) {
    switch (options.type) {
      case 'all':
        var myProjectCollection = new MyProjectCollection;

        myProjectCollection.fetch({
          success: function() {
            myProjectCollection.each(function(project) {

              this.project[project.id] = {};

              this.project[project.id].testObjects = new TestCollection([], {
                url: 'url/' + project.id,
                _type: 'test'
              });
            });
          }
        });
    }
  });

});
```

I've had a look around stack overflow, it does not appear to be the issue below (which seems to be the most common issue). 
[Model is not a constructor-Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034608/model-is-not-a-constructor-backbone)

I also do not think I have any circular dependencies.

Any help would be massively appreciated as I am completely stumped. I've tried to include only the relevant code, please let me know if additional code would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: If I attempt to console.log(TestModel) the line above return new TestModel() in the collection then 'undefined' is returned. However I can see that the file is loaded in the network tab of the browser. What is the best way to debug this?

Comment: Here's [how to store different model types in the same collection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40638871/1218980).

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for other parts of the code but an obvious problem you have is misunderstanding what data is passed to the model creator function.

```
var TestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: function(attrs) {
        switch (attrs._type) { // attrs._type does exist here
            console.log( attrs ); // Will print { foo: 'bar' }

            case 'test': // This will always be false since attrs._type does not exist 
                console.log('making a test model')
                return new TestModel();

            default: 
                return new Backbone.Model(); // Or return some other model instance, 
                                             // you MUST have this function return 
                                             // some kind of a Backbone.Model
        }
    },

    initialize : function(models, options){
        this.url = options.url;
        this._type = options._type;
        this.fetch({reset:true});
    }
});

new TestCollection([ { foo: 'bar' }], {
    url: 'url/' + project.id,
    _type: 'test' // This will NOT be passed to the model attrs, these are  
                  // options used for creating the Collection instance.
})
```

To re-iterate. When you instantiate a Collection you pass an array of plain objects `[{ foo: 'bar'}, { foo: 'baz'}]` ( or you get them via `fetch` like you're doing ). That object will be passed as the `attrs` parameter in the `model` function, and the `model` function MUST return at least some kind of a Backbone.Model instance so you need a fallback for your `switch` statement.